# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JPA

Tags: java

Пересмотрела все похожие вопросы, заданные раннее, не нашла подходящего ответа..

Вот мой persistence.xml :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="JPA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/menu?serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Для начала проверьте свою версию драйвера и бд, проверьте параметры урл( меня, к примеру, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false), а также обратите внимание на диалект. Попробуйте org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Не помогло

Comment: Что именно не помогло? ту сотня вариантов. Вы так быстро все проверили? Тогда выкладывайте свои классы, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Какая версия хибернет?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович https://github.com/KuzmaJava/MenuRestaurant

Comment: https://fex.net/866696977510 - пробуйте так... если не получится, то пишите. не забудьте исправить в урле имя базы данных

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Ничего не изменилось

Comment: У меня этот код работает. Осталась версия мускула и урл... Какая версия Вашей БД?\

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович 8

Comment: Workbench установлен? Подключение к БД с помощью Workbench  выполняется?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Воркбенч установлен, но с базой работаю через MySQL Command Line Client

Comment: https://fex.net/604876681377?fileId=1287482440 - пробуйте так

Comment: Попробуйте закоментировать `<provider>...`